# How to know if a set certain amount of strings match in 2 arrays

Tags: arrays, swift, if-statement, swift3

I have a simple line of code with 2 String Arrays. They both contain the same strings inside both arrays and I have an if statement that will work if both arrays are the same. Like so:

```
var firstArray: [String] = ["Music", "Art", "Sports", "Movies"]
var secondArray: [String] = ["Music", "Art", "Sports", "Movies"]

if firstArray == secondArray {

   //they match...
}
```

However, I want to be able to add a few more strings to the first array so the 2 arrays aren't fully the same, which will cancel out the if statement above **BUT** I want to run the if statement if 4 or more strings are the same in the second array as they are in the first array. How do I do this? Thank you.

Comment: Does the order of the elements matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the size of the intersection between the two arrays:

```
let firstArray = ["Music", "Art", "Sports", "Movies"]
let secondArray = ["Music", "Art", "Sports", "Movies"]

if firstArray == secondArray {
    print("equal")
}

if Set(firstArray).intersection(secondArray).count >= 4 {
    print("At least 4 are equal")
}
```

Keep in mind that converting an `Array` to a `Set` is a `O(n)` operation. If you're doing this often, cache the `Set` rather than recomputing it on every   check.

Comment: Thank you, Sir. Works perfectly!